# R.Java went missing in all projects

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I was working around with my Project when I noticed appcompat_v7. I didn't know what exactly that was, so I just deleted it. And now, none of my projects are generating R.java, even after cleaning and rebuilding. Did everything which I could find on the net, but all in vein. 
I managed to get back appcompat_v7 by making a new project, but even that wasn't generating R.java. I've messed it all up now, what to do next? How to get back R.java?

Comment: try doing this, App--> properties --> java build path -->  Order & Export -->un check Android Private Libraries than Ok & then clean.

Comment: @SmartphoneDeveloper uncheck what?

Comment: under Order & Export tab uncheck Android Private Libraries if it is checked. Then clean your project.

Comment: @SmartphoneDeveloper done, no use. :(

Comment: or do one more check.. App --> properties--> Android and then go down and check inside your Is Library box if any thing is in red their so remove & again Add your  appcompat_v7. then after then clean your project. Give it a try

Comment: & if nothing work plz once restart your Eclipse

Comment: @SmartphoneDeveloper Nope, same. Still error. And it shows error (red sign) above appcompat_v7 in project explorer too.

Comment: you messed up the builtin appcompat_v7. try re downloading it from valid source

Comment: @SmartphoneDeveloper Which is the valid source?

Comment: tell me one thing App --> properties--> Android what api level have you selected & what is your minimum App Api target

Comment: source https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Answer (score 0):

Strange fix but this workes
Right-click on the "appcompat_v7" project and go to -> Properties -> Android.
Your target build should already be set at the latest build (in my case Android 5.0.1). Click any other android package (apart from its current target) and click "Apply". Click "Ok" to close the box.
Re-open the Properties box by the same method but this time check the latest build (in my case Android 5.0.1) as the Project Build Target. Click "Apply", then "Ok" to close the box.
Clean the appcompat_v7 project. You'll probably need to clean/build all other projects that reference this library.
This solved it for me.

Comment: I did that all right, but still doesn't seem to work. Please help :/